# Timer delay in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer

```
// AS3
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);                  // 1 second
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, runMany);
myTimer.start();

function runMany(event:TimerEvent):void {
trace("runMany() called @ " + getTimer() + " ms");
}
```

Expected output:

```
runMany() called @ 1000 ms
```

Generated Output:

```
runMany() called @ 12823 ms
runMany() called @ 25603 ms
runMany() called @ 38404 ms
```

Is this due to some short of software problem? [I copied this easy code from Adobe Site](http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2006/07/using_the_timer_class_in_actio.html) but it's not working.

[image: on left AS3 code is written and in Output box undesired output is given]

Comment: Your code looks like it should work.  Do you have some other processing going on in your swf?

Comment: This image wasn't showing before, that is indeed strange. What system are you using?

Comment: @Brian thanks for the edit, I didn't see the image before

Comment: @S.Kumar Could you try your app in the browser (using a text field or ExternalInterface), and with another version of Flash Player ? And for you, are these traces taking really that time or they are just wrong values (you see a new trace every second but it's indicated a 12 seconds interval) ?

Comment: var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);

Comment: @Brian , no other processes are going on in swf.... and thanks for editing...i m new so didn't know much about how to posting codes...

Comment: @akmozo , yes the traces are really thating that long...i.e, 12 sec to print that one line.......

Comment: @Aaron , I m using window 10.... Adobe flash professional cs4..

Comment: @S.Kumar Did you tried it in the browser or another Flash Player version (even in another machine) ? Also, did you tried to create another Flash app with the same code (delete that app and create a new one) ? Could you also try the [`setInterval()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setInterval()) instead of a Timer object ? Could upload your swf to test it for you (use a text field or ExternalInterface for simple test) ?

Comment: **I GOT IT**......... in cs6 it's working,,,,,,in cs4 it wasn't working,,,maybe some software problem..... donot know the reason but it's working...........**THANKS EVERYONE**

Answer (score 0):

same code is working in flash CS6 actionscript 3.0 (gave unexpected O/P in CS4) so i think the problem might be of software. It said will installation that some features could not be installed properly and i ignored it....... Anyway Thanku all.